# WxPython ListCtrl: One Column with Images and One with a String

Tags: python, wxpython

I am having this issue and have tried almost everything. I want one column with images and one with strings. I can get the strings, but not the images.

Here is what I have:

```
self.browserList=wx.ListCtrl(panel, pos=(20,150), size=(250,100),   
style.wx.LC_REPORT|wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
self.browserList.InsertColumn(0, '', width=50)
self.browserList.InsertColumn(1, 'Browser: ', width=200)

self.list=wx.ImageList(40,40)
self.browserList.SetImageList(self.list, wx.IMAGE_LIST_NORMAL)
images=['Users/Default/Desktop/Project/firefoxlogo.png','Users/Default/Desktop/Project/chromelogo.png']
x=0
for i in images:
    img=wx.Image(i, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
    img=wx.BitmapFromImage(img)
    browserimg=self.list.Add(img)
    self.browserList.InsertImageItem(x, 0)
    self.browserList.InsertImageItem(x, 0, browserimg)

self.browserList.SetStringItem(0, 1, "Mozilla Firefox")
self.browserList.SetStringItem(1, 1, "Google Chrome")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get an error running your code.

But anyways, I can't explain why, but maybe I think you can resolve it by changing `wx.IMAGE_LIST_NORMAL` to `wx.IMAGE_LIST_SMALL`

Here is a simple code that I tried and worked for me.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title,size=(250, 250))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour('white')
        self.browserList=wx.ListCtrl(panel, pos=(20,150), size=(250,100),style = wx.LC_REPORT|wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        self.browserList.InsertColumn(0, '', width=50)
        self.browserList.InsertColumn(1, 'Browser: ', width=200)

        self.list=wx.ImageList(40,40)
        self.browserList.SetImageList(self.list, wx.IMAGE_LIST_SMALL)
        images=['mozilla.png','chrome.png']
        x=0
        for i in images:
            img=wx.Image(i, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
            img=wx.BitmapFromImage(img)
            browserimg=self.list.Add(img)
        self.browserList.InsertImageItem(x, 0)
        self.browserList.InsertImageItem(x, 1)

        self.browserList.SetStringItem(0, 1, "Mozilla Firefox")
        self.browserList.SetStringItem(1, 1, "Google Chrome")

class MyApp(wx.App):
     def OnInit(self):
         frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'frame')
         frame.Show(True)
         return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I made a small error with the "InsertImageItem". Anyways, do you know how I can lock the size of the listctrl so its a set size?

Answer (score 0):

First, an update of Deepas answer to the new wxPython Phoenix:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title,size=(250, 250))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour('white')
        self.browserList=wx.ListCtrl(panel, pos=(20,150), size=(300,300),style = wx.LC_REPORT|wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        self.browserList.InsertColumn(0, '', width=50)
        self.browserList.InsertColumn(1, 'Browser: ', width=200)

        self.list=wx.ImageList(100,100)
        self.browserList.SetImageList(self.list, wx.IMAGE_LIST_SMALL)
        images=['mozilla.png','chrome.png']
        x=0
        for i in images:
            img=wx.Image(i, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
            img=wx.Bitmap(img)
            browserimg=self.list.Add(img)
        self.browserList.InsertItem(x, 0)
        self.browserList.InsertItem(x, 1)

        self.browserList.SetItem(0, 1, "Mozilla Firefox")
        self.browserList.SetItem(1, 1, "Google Chrome")

class MyApp(wx.App):
     def OnInit(self):
         frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'frame')
         frame.Show(True)
         return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Then a general comment. It seems wxPython is not reference counting the ImageList. So, the user created owning class has to store it or no images will be shown (since it is garbage collected I guess). That is, the line

```
self.list=wx.ImageList(100,100)
```

**can not** be changed to

```
list=wx.ImageList(100,100)
```

Then on images will be shown.